# pdo order by relevance, then order by another field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that selects from my database and then orders by relevance:

```
select * from `table` where MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (:search2 IN BOOLEAN MODE) desc LIMIT :start, :limit
```

When these results are shown I want the user to have an option of filtering by price.  How can I do this when ORDER BY is already used for the relevance?

Can I create a view of the results and then query the view to filter by price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Order by as many columns as you want. Syntax is:

```
ORDER by column1 desc, column2 asc, column3 desc ...
```

So you might want to have:

```
select * from `table` where MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (:search2 IN BOOLEAN MODE) desc, `price` asc LIMIT :start, :limit
```

If you want a price Range you have to build it into an WHERE clause

```
select * from `table` where MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `price` >= 5 AND `price` < 10 order by MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (:search2 IN BOOLEAN MODE) desc, `price` asc LIMIT :start, :limit
```